What is triggering this popup "Enter the Apple ID Password for..."
Recently my computer began randomly showing a popup I've never seen before:
I haven't installed any new software and I'm not running any apps that I don't normally run. I this computer every day for work, approx 8 hours a day so it's odd to see something new like this. Also, to my knowledge I'm not running any "Apple Media Services" and have no idea what that would be referring to.
When I click "Cancel" it goes away for a while but comes back a few hours later.
What might be causing this popup? If there is no clear answer, how can I go about investigating?
This is a Mac Studio running macOS Sonoma 14.5.
I've left the popup active for now in hopes someone might be able to help pinpoint the specific process or application that's causing this.
UPDATE:
I grepped the last minute of my logs just now when this popup came back and got this:
log show --last 5m --style compact | grep -i mediaservice
2024-12-15 01:14:51.850 E  com.apple.AppStoreDaemon.StoreUIService[1182:1d5b55] [com.apple.AppleMediaServices:accounts] AMSUIAuthKitUpdateTask: [C7684158] The AuthKit authentication failed. error = { Error domain=AKAuthenticationError, code=-7003
2024-12-15 01:14:51.850 E  com.apple.AppStoreDaemon.StoreUIService[1182:1d5b55] [com.apple.AppleMediaServices:action] AMSUIAuthKitUpdateTask: [C7684158] === Failed === -> error = { Error domain=AKAuthenticationError, code=-7003
2024-12-15 01:14:51.850 Df com.apple.AppStoreDaemon.StoreUIService[1182:1d5b55] [com.apple.AppleMediaServices:accounts] AMSUIAuthenticateTask: [C7684158] Failed to generate a password. error = { Error domain=AKAuthenticationError, code=-7003
2024-12-15 01:14:51.851 E  com.apple.AppStoreDaemon.StoreUIService[1182:1d5b55] [com.apple.AppleMediaServices:accounts] AMSUIAuthenticateTask: [C7684158] The authentication failed. error = { Error domain=AMSErrorDomain, code=6, underlyingError={ { Error domain=AMSErrorDomain, code=100, multipleUnderlyingErrors=[ { Error domain=AMSErrorDomain, code=2{ Error domain=AKAuthenticationError, code=-7003 ] }
2024-12-15 01:14:51.851 E  com.apple.AppStoreDaemon.StoreUIService[1182:1d5b55] [com.apple.AppleMediaServices:action] AMSUIAuthenticateTask: [C7684158] === Failed === -> error = { Error domain=AMSErrorDomain, code=6, underlyingError={ { Error domain=AMSErrorDomain, code=100, multipleUnderlyingErrors=[ { Error domain=AMSErrorDomain, code=2{ Error domain=AKAuthenticationError, code=-7003 ] }
2024-12-15 01:14:52.602 E  com.apple.AppStoreDaemon.StoreUIService[1182:1d5b60] [com.apple.AppleMediaServices:accounts] AMSUIAuthKitUpdateTask: [C7684158] The AuthKit authentication failed. error = { Error domain=AKAuthenticationError, code=-7045
2024-12-15 01:14:52.602 E  com.apple.AppStoreDaemon.StoreUIService[1182:1d5b60] [com.apple.AppleMediaServices:action] AMSUIAuthKitUpdateTask: [C7684158] === Failed === -> error = { Error domain=AKAuthenticationError, code=-7045
2024-12-15 01:14:52.602 Df com.apple.AppStoreDaemon.StoreUIService[1182:1d5b60] [com.apple.AppleMediaServices:accounts] AMSUIAuthenticateTask: [C7684158] Failed to generate a password. error = { Error domain=AKAuthenticationError, code=-7045
2024-12-15 01:14:52.602 E  com.apple.AppStoreDaemon.StoreUIService[1182:1d5b60] [com.apple.AppleMediaServices:accounts] AMSUIAuthenticateTask: [C7684158] The authentication failed. error = { Error domain=AMSErrorDomain, code=100, multipleUnderlyingErrors=[ { Error domain=AMSErrorDomain, code=2{ Error domain=AKAuthenticationError, code=-7045 ]
2024-12-15 01:14:52.603 E  com.apple.AppStoreDaemon.StoreUIService[1182:1d5b60] [com.apple.AppleMediaServices:action] AMSUIAuthenticateTask: [C7684158] === Failed === -> error = { Error domain=AMSErrorDomain, code=100, multipleUnderlyingErrors=[ { Error domain=AMSErrorDomain, code=2{ Error domain=AKAuthenticationError, code=-7045 ]
2024-12-15 01:14:52.737 E  com.apple.AppStoreDaemon.StoreUIService[1182:1d5b60] [com.apple.AppleMediaServices:accounts] AMSUIAuthKitUpdateTask: [C7684158] The AuthKit authentication failed. error = { Error domain=AKAuthenticationError, code=-7045
2024-12-15 01:14:52.737 E  com.apple.AppStoreDaemon.StoreUIService[1182:1d5b60] [com.apple.AppleMediaServices:action] AMSUIAuthKitUpdateTask: [C7684158] === Failed === -> error = { Error domain=AKAuthenticationError, code=-7045
2024-12-15 01:14:52.737 Df com.apple.AppStoreDaemon.StoreUIService[1182:1d5b60] [com.apple.AppleMediaServices:accounts] AMSUIAuthenticateTask: [C7684158] Failed to generate a password. error = { Error domain=AKAuthenticationError, code=-7045
2024-12-15 01:14:52.737 E  com.apple.AppStoreDaemon.StoreUIService[1182:1d5b60] [com.apple.AppleMediaServices:accounts] AMSUIAuthenticateTask: [C7684158] The authentication failed. error = { Error domain=AMSErrorDomain, code=100, multipleUnderlyingErrors=[ { Error domain=AMSErrorDomain, code=2{ Error domain=AKAuthenticationError, code=-7045 ]
2024-12-15 01:14:52.737 E  com.apple.AppStoreDaemon.StoreUIService[1182:1d5b60] [com.apple.AppleMediaServices:action] AMSUIAuthenticateTask: [C7684158] === Failed === -> error = { Error domain=AMSErrorDomain, code=100, multipleUnderlyingErrors=[ { Error domain=AMSErrorDomain, code=2{ Error domain=AKAuthenticationError, code=-7045 ]
2024-12-15 01:14:52.881 E  com.apple.AppStoreDaemon.StoreUIService[1182:1d5b55] [com.apple.AppleMediaServices:accounts] AMSUIAuthKitUpdateTask: [C7684158] The AuthKit authentication failed. error = { Error domain=AKAuthenticationError, code=-7045
2024-12-15 01:14:52.881 E  com.apple.AppStoreDaemon.StoreUIService[1182:1d5b55] [com.apple.AppleMediaServices:action] AMSUIAuthKitUpdateTask: [C7684158] === Failed === -> error = { Error domain=AKAuthenticationError, code=-7045
2024-12-15 01:14:52.882 Df com.apple.AppStoreDaemon.StoreUIService[1182:1d5b55] [com.apple.AppleMediaServices:accounts] AMSUIAuthenticateTask: [C7684158] Failed to generate a password. error = { Error domain=AKAuthenticationError, code=-7045
2024-12-15 01:14:52.882 E  com.apple.AppStoreDaemon.StoreUIService[1182:1d5b55] [com.apple.AppleMediaServices:accounts] AMSUIAuthenticateTask: [C7684158] The authentication failed. error = { Error domain=AMSErrorDomain, code=100, multipleUnderlyingErrors=[ { Error domain=AMSErrorDomain, code=2{ Error domain=AKAuthenticationError, code=-7045 ]
2024-12-15 01:14:52.882 E  com.apple.AppStoreDaemon.StoreUIService[1182:1d5b55] [com.apple.AppleMediaServices:action] AMSUIAuthenticateTask: [C7684158] === Failed === -> error = { Error domain=AMSErrorDomain, code=100, multipleUnderlyingErrors=[ { Error domain=AMSErrorDomain, code=2{ Error domain=AKAuthenticationError, code=-7045 ]


Please sign out of your account in the Music and Books apps, then sign back in. Any change?

@LincDavis - I am not currently signed in on either of those apps. I have never even launched "Books" before. I don't think I've ever logged in to "Music" and it's not something I typically use. I did, however, recently connect an old iPod to this computer and moved some music onto it.  I wonder if that's where the trouble started...

If that music came from Apple Music (or the iTunes Music Store, as it used to be called) and was purchased with a different Apple ID, that could well be the cause.

It didn't but there might have been something like that at play. At any rate, assuming we are on the right track. How do I make these popups stop? Music ran once a week ago. It has not run since. The popups keep coming... I'm thinking there must be a process I can kill or something along those lines.

I doubt that killing a process would do any good, because it would just restart immediately. You could try logging out, if you haven't already done that. Otherwise, the next time you see the password prompt, note the exact time, then launch the Console app and see whether there are any log messages from exactly that time that seem related. I can't be more specific, because I can't reproduce the problem. If you find anything, add it to your original question. Please post the text as a code block, not a screenshot.

@LincDavis - I recently had a power outage and this popup started happening again. I launched console as you suggested but there are no messages. There is a "start" button on console that will start streaming current messages but I don't see any way to view things that happened before the app was open. This is definitely not how it used to operate. I know this is going sideways but do you have any idea how to view console messages from before the app was opened and "start" clicked?

The following shell command will print all log messages from the last minute. There will be far too many to post, so you'll have to be somewhat selective: log show --last 1m --style compact

Those log messages just show that you were prompted for a password and didn't provide it, or the password was wrong. Looking back at this thread, it's not clear that you ever did enter the password. Have you done that?

@LincDavis - I might have at some point, can't remember. At this point I jut want to be left alone. I don't want to sign in to the app store or use media services. I click "Cancel" and the popup simply comes back after a while. I don't understand the philosophy behind this kind of engineering.

Let's go back to your comment about the old iPod. Did you move music from the Mac to the iPod or vice versa? Also, please sign out of the App Store and sign back in.

Did you move music from the Mac to the iPod or vice versa? Yes I believe I did move music from the Mac to the iPod.

please sign out of the App Store and sign back in. As I mentioned above, I don't want to be signed in to the App store on this computer.

If you believe that you have no App Store products installed and no content from any of the content stores, then there must be something you don't know about. Is it asking too much for you to sign in to the App Store just once? You can sign back out if nothing changes.

I'm not saying I have no app store products installed, I'm saying that I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve me being signed in. I have signed in in the past. I'm perfectly fine with signing in and out again. Are you suggesting that that series of actions will possibly solve the issue? I really appreciate your help, but it's a bit frustrating that MacOS behaviour is so mysterious. TBH, I just want to know why this is happening. Even if wild guesses somehow make it stop, I still will likely be left without a real answer.

It's mysterious to me too, because Apple doesn't document the alert and I could find only one similar report to yours, with no resolution. I think the most likely explanation is that you have content on the machine that was downloaded under a different Apple ID, or that you need to authenticate your own Apple ID. Tracking that down could be quite hard to do, so I'm suggesting an easy step with the chance of saving you some work. I'm not going to try to sell you on the idea. It's a suggestion and you're of course free to ignore it.

@LincDavis - this may be of interest. I went to the App Store and it appears that it thinks I am still "Signed In" - despite the machine rebooting several times since. Attempting to do anything presents a dialog that prompts me to "sign in". Whoever designed this is an idiot.  My best guess is that they save the "signed in" state, whether or not the session has expired and then periodically pester you to sign in again even though the actual  state is not signed in.  I hope that makes sense. I've now "signed out" - we'll see if that stops the madness.
